# pg_replication_slots: how to determine how far behind a consumer is?

Tags: postgresql, replication

Given the replication api exposed in postgres 9.6.6, for a given replication slot and a consumer, what system catalogs or view could inform how far behind the consumer was the latest state of the wal?

Answer (score 1):

The view you are looking for is [pg_stat_replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-REPLICATION-VIEW).  In 9.6 you can only get this info expressed in LSN, not clock time.  Starting in v10, you can get it in clock time.